# Strange Media Queries behaviour in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Something strange happens when I use media queries in Firefox.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="test"></div>

@media (min-width: 701px) {
    div.test { background-color: yellow; }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    div.test { background-color: blue; }
}
```

What I am expecting to happen here is the test-div to have a blue background when the window is <= 700px, and for the test div to become yellow when the window is >= 701px.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmtanujf/embedded/result/

If you open this fullscreen (in Firefox, latest version) and then use Ctrl+Shift+M,
you can set the window size to for example: 702 x 300, and you will notice that it doesn't set a background. Why does this happen?

Comment: Seems to work perfectly OK in latest version of Firefox for me.

Comment: Yes...this side works fine.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it might have something to do with my windows scaling set at 125%.

Comment: @P.Henderson: It probably does. Pixel-based anything and OS scaling simply don't work very well together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the version of your firefox. You have to update your firefox version to the latest update